# Batch upload to the Parse API

Tags: android, batch-file, upload, parse-platform

I am an app developer I am using Parse and loving it. However, my app depends on data created by me and not my users. For example, a trivia app that has the info loaded by the user, so I have to create this content to serve to my users. But this content is made of text, and links, and a image.

Suppose I have 500 of these objects, how do I send them all to my Parse application? I have to upload the link, text and image.

Is there any way to do that? I see many apps that depend on data curated the the app developers? How to handle this problem? Manual upload seems like craziness when you have a lot of objects.

Thanks!

Comment: What format do you currently have this data in? You could write a script or a small program to upload that data.

Comment: I can format the data in any way, CSV or JSON or whatever. The format of the data that I have is not a problem, imo. Do you know how can I possibly upload an image to Parse from my local file system?

Comment: If use the REST API (https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#files) you can pretty much use any programming language of your choice to write a utility program or use curl in a shell script.